# SQL Server 2008 query for forward cash flow report

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I am currently working on SSRS report that should display estimated Cash Flow for the user defined period eg: 1 year ahead

My table looks like below:

```
ID  DepositDate  DepositAmt  BalanceDueDate  TotalAmount  
--------------------------------------------------------  
1   02/06/2011   10%         02/07/2011              100
2   16/06/2011   10%         16/07/2011              200
3   08/07/2011   20%         08/08/2011              300
4   15/07/2011   10%         15/08/2011              400
```

process

```
Month  Amount
-------------
06         10 (10% (deposit %) of Total amount for ID 1)
06         20 (10% of Total amount for ID 2)
07         90 (balance amount after deposit from previous month for ID 1)
07        180 (balance amount after deposit from previous month for ID 2)
07         60 (20% of Total amount for ID 3)
07         40 (10% of Total amount for ID 4)
08        240 (balance amount after deposit from previous month for ID 3)
08        360 (balance amount after deposit from previous month for ID 4)
```

Expected output

```
Month  Amount
-------------
06         30
07        370
08        600
```

Tried some queries with CTE, but I am lost.

can anybody shed some light?

Many thanks

Comment: Is the gap between deposit and balance always one month? Can we assume it will always be the same day of the month, i.e. a deposit on the 2nd will have a balance of the 2nd?

Comment: No, the gap between two dates can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT  [Month],
        SUM(Amount) Amount
FROM (  SELECT  MONTH(DepositDate) [Month],
                DepositAmt * TotalAmount Amount
        FROM YourTable

        UNION ALL
        SELECT  MONTH(BalanceDueDate),
                TotalAmount * (1 - DepositAmt)
        FROM YourTable) A
GROUP BY [Month]
ORDER BY [Month]
```

Results:

```
╔═══════╦════════╗
║ Month ║ Amount ║
╠═══════╬════════╣
║     6 ║     30 ║
║     7 ║    370 ║
║     8 ║    600 ║
╚═══════╩════════╝
```

[**Here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90f99/1) with a demo.

You should think of adding the year on your result set, though, otherwise you can mix your results.

Comment: Excellent! I will give a try. Thanks for your suggestion regarding the inclusion of year.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one which will handle multiple month periods:

```
with CashMovements as
(
  select *
    , CashMovement = DepositAmt * TotalAmount
    , CashPaid = DepositAmt * TotalAmount
  from Deposits
  union all
  select ID
    , dateadd(mm,1,DepositDate)
    , DepositAmt
    , BalanceDueDate
    , TotalAmount
    , CashMovement = case when dateadd(Month,1,DepositDate) >= BalanceDueDate
        then TotalAmount - CashPaid
      else DepositAmt * TotalAmount
      end
    , CashPaid = case when dateadd(mm,1,DepositDate) >= BalanceDueDate
        then CashPaid + (DepositAmt * TotalAmount)
      else 0.0
      end
  from CashMovements
  where dateadd(Month,1,DepositDate) <= BalanceDueDate
)
select Month = Month(DepositDate)
  , Amount = sum(CashMovement)
from CashMovements
group by Month(DepositDate)
order by Month
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/afac9/2).

If you're data doesn't need to consider this case best to go with the simple solution from @Lamak.